# Why does tableVieW:viewForHeaderInSection ignore the frame property of my UILabel?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, frame

Basically I want to change the font and the color of my section header, so I implement `tableVieW:viewForHeaderInSection`. First I tried this code:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel* headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 40);
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    headerLabel.text = @"My section header";

    return headerLabel;
}
```

but for some reason the frame property is ignored (I'm talking about the 10px inset on the left). Now I use the following:

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView* headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40)] autorelease];

    UILabel* headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, 300, 40);
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
    headerLabel.text = @"My section header";

    [headerView addSubview:headerLabel];
    [headerLabel release];

    return headerView;
}
```

with the desired results. Can someone explain to me why the second approach works and the first doesn't?

PS. In both cases I implement `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection` as well, returning 40.0

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's because the UITableView automatically sets the frame of the header view you provide to

`(0, y, table view width, header view height)`

`y` is the computed position of the view and
`header view height` is the value returned by `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:`

Comment: Then I really need the "headerView" in my code in order to get this inset, right?

Comment: It would also work to just prepend some spaces in front of the text in the label, that's a good trick for quick UILabel adjustment.

Comment: This behaves differently in iOS 7 for my case. It's adding 1 pt padding to both sides of the headerView in iOS 7. Do you guys see the same?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's better do add a subview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 5, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 20))
    label.text = "\(sections[section].year)"
    view.addSubview(label)
    return view
}
```